# Mysql before insert Trigger to fetchdata from one table and insert to another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Below is my monthly salary table for user

```
+-------+------------+
|user_id|user_salary |
+-------+------------+
| 6     | 10000      |
+-------+------------+
```

And this is my daily attendance table

```
+-------------+---------+------+-------+---------------+-------+
|attendance_id| user_id |name  |present|attendance_date| wages |
+-------------+---------+------+-------+---------------+-------+
| 1   |       | 6       | parth| P     |2016-12-16     |  350  |  
+-------------+---------+------+-------+---------------+-------+
```

Above is my salary and attendance table, i want to insert per day wages as per monthly salary and insert to attendance table using trigger below is my trigger code. I want per day=monthly_salary/days_in_month and insert to attendance wages table.

```
trigger wages before insert on attendance 
for each row
set NEW.wages=(select user_salary from salary where user_id=NEW.user_id)/(SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(now())))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `attendance`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.wages = (SELECT user_salary from salary where user_id = NEW.user_id)/(SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(now())));
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the command `CREATE` in your `BEFORE INSERT ON` line.

A working example would be:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `attendance`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 SET NEW.room = (SELECT user_salary from salary where user_id=NEW.user_id)/(SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(now())));
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Just fixed the SELECT statement. If you're happy with my answer, please accept it. Thank you.